# Why am I getting a NotSerializableException here?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to map a function across a JavaRDD in spark, and I keep getting `NotSerializableError` on the `map` call.

```
public class SparkPrunedSet extends AbstractSparkSet {

    private final ColumnPruner pruner;

    public SparkPrunedSet(@JsonProperty("parent") SparkSet parent, @JsonProperty("pruner") ColumnPruner     pruner) {
        super(parent);
        this.pruner = pruner;
    }

    public JavaRDD<Record> getRdd(SparkContext context) {
        JavaRDD<Record> rdd = getParent().getRdd(context);
        Function<Record, Record> mappingFunction = makeRecordTransformer(pruner);

        //The line below throws the error
        JavaRDD<Record> mappedRdd = rdd.map(mappingFunction);
        return mappedRdd;
    }

    private Function<Record, Record> makeRecordTransformer() {
        return new Function<Record, Record>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Record call(Record record) throws Exception {
                // Obviously i'd like to do something more useful in here, but this is enough
                // to throw the error
                return record;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When it runs, I get:
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.package.SparkPrunedSet

`Record` is an interface that implements serializable, and `MapRecord` is an implementation of it. Similar code to this exists and works in the codebase, except it's using `rdd.filter` instead. I've read through most of the other stack overflow entries on this, and none of them seem to help. I thought it might have to do with troubles serializing `SparkPrunedSet` (although I don't understand why it would even need to do this), so I set all of the fields on it to `transient`, but that didn't help either. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does any of the parent classes in implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Any of the parent classes in what?

Comment: Any of the parent classes of `SparkPrunedSet`, seeing that it is the one that is rejected for not being `Serializable`.

Comment: No, but I don't understand why it would be need to be serialized. I've even got another class that extends `AbstractSparkSet` with very similar code, (basically replace the `rdd.map` call above with a `rdd.filter` call).

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with the fact that the `Function` object you are passing to it is of an (anonymous) inner class of `SparkPrunedSet`, and therefore has an internal reference to it.

Comment: Ah, that actually makes sense! I forgot inner classes have an implicit reference to their parent, even if you don't use it. I changed the `makeRecordTransformer` into a static call, and everything worked out. If you want to make this into a real answer, I'll gladly upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Function` you are creating for the transformation is, in fact, an (anonymous) inner class of `SparkPrunedSet`. Therefore every instance of that function has an implicit reference to the `SparkPrunedSet` object that created it.

Therefore, serialization of it will require serialization of `SparkPrunedSet`.